# convert unsigned int *' to 'unsigned int *&

Tags: c++

I have a function which gets 'unsigned int *& argument
The parameter I want to transfer in my code is located in the `std::vector<unsigned int>  data`
So,what I do is : I transfer the following parameter &data[0]
But get the compilation error:

```
unsigned int *' to 'unsigned int *&
```

What can be a work around?
Thanks,

Comment: _Why_ would you want to transfer a `unsigned int *&` in the first place?

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall - I don`t :) but I use the functon which gets int*&

Comment: There really isn't enough info for a real answer. Right now, the answer is simply "you can't, what you're asking doesn't make sense, you can't change the address of a vector's elements directly". However, what you should do instead depends on what that function does and why it needs a reference to a pointer.

Comment: What exactly does this function that takes an `unsigned int *&` do with it? Ususally, when a function takes a parameter by non-`const`-reference, it means that it's going to *write* to that parameter. That it's an output. And since the parameter is a pointer, that sounds like it's going to allocate memory into it or something.

Comment: You could make the opposite of `std::move`, which I'd call `std::stay`: `template <typename T> T & stay(T && x) { return static_cast<T &>(x); }` (But I agree that it's very likely you're doing something wrong.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`&data[0]` is an rvalue and cannot be bound to non-const reference.

You can make it work this way:

```
unsigned int *ptr = &data[0];
func(ptr);
```

But possibly it's better to just change the signature of your function to

```
void foo(unsigned int &val); //or any other return type
```

There is a sense of passing a reference to a pointer in case you want to make a pointer point somewhere else. But I don't see a reason to do so in your case

Comment: what can be a possible solution?

Answer (score 3):

The expression `&data[0]` yields indeed an r-value, which your function cannot accept.

A simple work-around if you don't want to alter your function (make sure you understand the reasons it requires a reference):

```
unsigned int* ptr = &data[0];
func(ptr);
```

Answer (score 1):

&data[0] is a rvalue, but the function parameter type is *non-constant* reference to a pointer. A non-const reference can't be bound to an rvalue.

It's hard to suggest a good workaround until OP provides more context for his problem.

Comment: No, the type is definitely *not* `const unsigned int*` unless `data` is const in that context.

Comment: @celtschk: Thank you for pointing out, I corrected the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Write

```
unsigned int *argument = &data[0];
call_function(argument);
```

Be aware that the function may be expecting to change the value of `argument`, so it may expect you to then write:

```
data.assign(argument, argument + new_length);
```

Comment: I'd first check if it really did, i.e. `if (argument != &data[0]) data.assign(...);`